# How to activate cube and related Compiz features without crashing Unity?

Tags: unity, compiz, cube

I have activated Desktop cube feature in Compiz by editing the config file way in this [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/compiz-cube-natty/):

1. Preference >> Export
2. Open the exported profile and edit it
3. Find “s0_active_plugins” and replace wall with cube ; rotate;
4. Save it.
5. Preference >> Import as... and make the new profile.

But after that, if I tried to activate any feature in Compiz, the Unity crashes. What to do to activate (3D windows) and (cube reflection and decoration) and any other features without crashing unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to Enable Compliz on Ubuntu 11.10](http://ubuntuguide.net/enable-compiz-desktop-cube-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-unity/) I have actually followed this and it works on my setup. If you do decide to follow this guide, you should create a ccsm shortcut on your desktop for use when you log back in. I also had to hit Ctrl + Alt + F1, and log in and restart lightdm by issuing the following:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

It came to a standard login box, once logged in I was unable to use Alt + F2 to try and run ccsm. Luckily, I did have a launcher for a different application. I just created a copy of the launcher and changed the path to "ccsm" and was able to launch ccsm that way.

Comment: thanks a very good link, but without a shortcut for ccsm i use the terminal as in the link

Comment: Cool, with my experience, I couldn't open a terminal, so I improvised :-)

Comment: hahah, can be opened with `Ctrl+Alt+T`

Comment: I know how it usually can be opened with that combo, but it wasn't able to open for me for some reason at that time. Possibly because I have been playing around with other window manager. If I press Ctrl+Alt+T on any of my other machines, a terminal opens.... Just not this one.